# Tkinter image not configuring properly onto button

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button, interface

I am trying to configure a button to turn it into a clickable image using Tkinter but when I try to configure a button, the button shrinks into a small black rectangle and does not show the image. This happens when running the code below. Why does this happen?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

UiBoard = []
DataBoard = []

count=0
for row in range(0,8):
        UiBoard.append([])
        for col in range(0,8):
                val = str(row) + str(col)
                DataBoard.append(val)

                # Change the board colour
                if ((col%2)==0 and ((row%2)==0)):
                        UiBoard[row].append(tk.Button(root, text="", width=6, height=3, bg="Black", fg="White" , bd = 0))
                        UiBoard[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col)
                elif ((col%2)==1 and ((row%2)==1)):
                        UiBoard[row].append(tk.Button(root, text="", width=6, height=3, bg="Black", fg="White" , bd = 0))
                        UiBoard[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col)
                else:
                        UiBoard[row].append(tk.Button(root, text="", width=6, height=3, bg="White", bd = 0))
                        UiBoard[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col)
                count+=1

click_btn= PhotoImage(file='pawn.png')
UiBoard[0][0].configure(image = click_btn)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because you have set the width and height of the button to 6 and 3 which will be in pixels when image is added.

Comment: set `bd = 0` to `bd = 5` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set `width=6` and `height=3`. Without setting the image, the values are in characters and lines, but they will be in pixels after image is added.  That's why the button with the image becomes so small (`6x3`).

One of the way is to create a *blank image* with the same size as the chess piece image and add it to all the buttons, then you don't need to specify the `width` and `height` options when creating the buttons:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

UiBoard = []
DataBoard = []

pawn = tk.PhotoImage(file='pawn.png')
w, h = pawn.width(), pawn.height() # get the image size

blank = tk.PhotoImage(width=w, height=h) # create blank image with same size
for row in range(8):
    UiBoard.append([])
    for col in range(8):
        DataBoard.append(f"{row}{col}")
        # Change the board colour
        color = "white" if (row+col)%2 else "black"
        UiBoard[row].append(tk.Button(root, bg=color, bd=0, image=blank))
        UiBoard[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col)

UiBoard[0][0].configure(image=pawn)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]